# Constriant variation not updating when switching to landscape mode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have an app that can be used in both portrait and landscape mode, I have a set of images that have constraints that change depending on their variation. Switching from landscape to portrait is fine but switching from portrait to landscape, the constraints take time to update.

I have tried calling `layoutIfNeeded()` on `viewWillTransition()`, which is called on rotate, to force the UI to update but that doesn't work. The only way I can get it to consistently work is by performing a segue or loading the page in landscape.

Here is the code I used in `viewWillTransition()`:

```
    override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
```

Here is my view.
[image: Image of interface builder]

Here are my constraints in the view hierarchy:

[image: View Hierarchy]

Here is an example of one of the constraints:

[image: Top Constraint]

This constraint was for vertical spacing, the horizontal spacing variation is just the opposite.

Here is what it should look like in landscape mode:

[image: Correct landscape constraints]

Here is what it actually looks like in landscape mode:

[image: Incorrect landscape constriants]

What is trying to be achieved is constraints being added or removed on rotations. I want to avoid messing with constraints in the code,

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one approach, using constraints and `Vary for Traits`. It's all done in IB / Storyboard, so no need for any code.

Start by adding your image view to the view controller, and set constraints:

- Aspect Ratio: `275:375`
- Centered X and Y
- Width equal to Safe-Area Width
- Top / Leading / Trailing / Bottom all set to `0` (Safe-Area Margins)
- Change the `Priority` for Top / Leading / Trailing / Bottom constraints to `999`

It should look like this:

[image]

Select Landscape Orientation. As you know, it will *not* look the way you want it to look:

[image]

So:

- Click `Vary for Traits`
- Select `Height`
- In the right-hand Size Inspector pane, delete the Equal Width constraint (it will turn light-gray)
- Add a new Height Equal to Safe-Area constraint

[image]

Click `Done Varying`.

Your image view will now be centered in the view, and it will maintain its `275:375` aspect ratio in both orientations / size classes.

Here is the Storyboard source:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="14490.70" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" useSafeAreas="YES" colorMatched="YES">
    <device id="retina4_7" orientation="landscape">
        <adaptation id="fullscreen"/>
    </device>
    <dependencies>
        <deployment identifier="iOS"/>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="14490.49"/>
        <capability name="Safe area layout guides" minToolsVersion="9.0"/>
        <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
    </dependencies>
    <scenes>
        <!--View Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="Bjw-UZ-DBh">
            <objects>
                <viewController id="ieI-bT-Ifq" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="CRw-bL-GPR">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="667" height="375"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                        <subviews>
                            <imageView clipsSubviews="YES" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="scaleAspectFit" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="Dkh-gb-NGL">
                                <rect key="frame" x="196" y="0.0" width="275" height="375"/>
                                <constraints>
                                    <constraint firstAttribute="width" secondItem="Dkh-gb-NGL" secondAttribute="height" multiplier="275:375" id="TKh-gG-4pv"/>
                                </constraints>
                            </imageView>
                        </subviews>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
                        <constraints>
                            <constraint firstItem="Dkh-gb-NGL" firstAttribute="centerX" secondItem="CRw-bL-GPR" secondAttribute="centerX" id="661-mS-m3k"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="Y5s-dY-VC9" firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="Dkh-gb-NGL" secondAttribute="bottom" priority="999" id="GaN-7z-lVZ"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="Y5s-dY-VC9" firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="Dkh-gb-NGL" secondAttribute="trailing" priority="999" id="JGP-UA-UW1"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="Dkh-gb-NGL" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="Y5s-dY-VC9" secondAttribute="leading" priority="999" id="Ovt-ZN-Wnu"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="Dkh-gb-NGL" firstAttribute="height" secondItem="Y5s-dY-VC9" secondAttribute="height" id="SiU-Zw-7fX"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="Dkh-gb-NGL" firstAttribute="width" secondItem="Y5s-dY-VC9" secondAttribute="width" id="aZQ-wg-aLj"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="Dkh-gb-NGL" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="Y5s-dY-VC9" secondAttribute="top" priority="999" id="set-8q-bm8"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="Dkh-gb-NGL" firstAttribute="centerY" secondItem="CRw-bL-GPR" secondAttribute="centerY" id="w9T-up-viV"/>
                        </constraints>
                        <viewLayoutGuide key="safeArea" id="Y5s-dY-VC9"/>
                        <variation key="default">
                            <mask key="constraints">
                                <exclude reference="SiU-Zw-7fX"/>
                            </mask>
                        </variation>
                        <variation key="heightClass=compact">
                            <mask key="constraints">
                                <include reference="SiU-Zw-7fX"/>
                                <exclude reference="aZQ-wg-aLj"/>
                            </mask>
                        </variation>
                    </view>
                </viewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="f3U-tR-QDM" userLabel="First Responder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="86" y="135"/>
        </scene>
    </scenes>
</document>
```